# How the matlab code gives a strange output and How to explain it?

Tags: matlab

I understand how the program works but I have a little bit of confusion. If anybody can explain, that will be great. The output is 21, 12. Does it work like 7*3=21 and 4*3=12?

```
mat=[7 11 3; 3:5];
[r,c]=size(mat);
for i=1:r
    fprintf ('The sum is %d\n',sum(mat(i,:)))
end
```

Comment: You're using the function `sum`, clearly this is a sum. If you're unsure how `sum` works then see the docs, it's summing each row here.

Answer (score 1):

`mat(i,:)` will give you all values in the first row of `mat`. In your example, this first row is `[7 11 3]`, and the second row is `[3 4 5]`. The outputs you're seeing are the sums of all values in each row (7+11+3=21).